# Android wallpaper program layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, wallpaper

When I look at several of the more popular android walpaper programs, (HD Wallpapers and the like), they all seem to have a very similar layout with 4 pictures in a 2 x 2 grid where each takes up approximately 1/2 of the parent's respective width and height. After not having a lot of success emulating this with various combinations of layouts and objects, I am trolling for a pointer. Anyone who could get me pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Is there a standard mix to achieve this sort of view?

Side note: Please be gentle, it's my first time... asking a question. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `GridView` with `android:numColumns=2`.

You can see a `GridView` example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).  You would set the height by manipulating the `LayoutParams` on the views that you put inside the GridView (via its `Adapter`).

If that doesn't float your boat and you're not doing much scrolling, you can always create a TableLayout with TableRows of 2 Views apiece, or a vertical LinearLayout containing two horizontal LinearLayouts of 2 Views apiece.

What have you tried already?  Can you expand on your use case a little bit more?  Do the images need to scroll?  Can they be static?  Will there be more than 4 images on a page?

Comment: Im not doing any sort of scrolling. It will be a 2 by 2 grid of pictures with a border above and below. I think the table layout may do the trick. I am going to give it a whirl. Thank you.